# Unix. Checksum of all files in directory and it's subdirectories

Tags: unix

I have a question. It's a part of my homework and i really dont know how to do it.
I have an archive that contains the tree of directories and a file called sumy.md5. I have to search every file in this tree and check if their checksums are also in sumy.md5 file. If they are i have to move them to another directory. 
I would be very grateful if someone could tell me how to go through the whole directory and check if the checksum of a file is also in file sumy.md5

The code I have tried so far.

```
for f in (find ./AA/* -type f ) 
while read -r file; 
do
 b=$(md5sum $file | cut -d' ' -f1)
 if [ $a == $b ] then 
  echo "Found It" 
   else echo "File not found" 
 fi 
done < sumy.md5
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This sounds like a straight forward bash script would work

Comment: for f in (find ./AA/* -type f )
       while read -r file; do
             b=$(md5sum $file | cut -d' ' -f1)
             if [ $a == $b  ]
             then
                      echo "Found It"
             else
                      echo "File not found"
             fi
     done < sumy.md5

Comment: Writing code is one part of homework. Sometimes overlooked is the skill of breaking down a problem into smaller parts. It sounds like your homework has several steps: (1) looking through a directory tree, (2) checking md5 for the file, (3) making a decision whether to move the file, and (4) moving the file. Which part(s) are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your script. Copying your comment and formatting:

```sh
# the following line has a syntax error (missing "$")
# but it's also not used in the loop
for f in (find ./AA/* -type f )
# syntax error here trying to jump into the while loop
while read -r file; do 

    b=$(md5sum $file | cut -d' ' -f1)

    # the variable "a" is never defined
    if [ $a == $b ]
    then
        echo "Found It"
    else
        echo "File not found"
    fi
done < sumy.md5
```

The above seems to iterate over the files in the directory (incorrectly), then iterate over every line in the sumy.md5 file. If the md5 contents are output from `md5sum` then you could probably just use the `--check` option, but if not, it's easier just to search the contents using something like grep.

```sh
for file in $( find ./AA/* -type f )
do
    b=$(md5sum $file | cut -d' ' -f1)

    # "q" just exits with status code, 0 or 1 on found or not
    # "i" says to ignore case
    if grep -qi "$b" "sumy.md5"
    then
        echo "Found It"
    else
        echo "File not found"
    fi
done
```

If found, use something like `cp --parents` or maybe `rsync` to copy the file to whatever directory, and that will also create the required directory structure without having to deal with it manually.

Comment: Thank you sir :) You version seems to be better and easier . This is really helpful.  I didn't even think about grep. I will learn how to use proper format of pasting code but my exam is comming and for now i dont really have much time . There is one more problem. I also have to make symbolic links to the moved files. Paths that are in symbolic links  have to be relative.